# Maintain aspect ratio of resized bitmap

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I implemented this to resize bitmap and preserve aspect ratio which worked but I wonder if there is a way to implement this such that all the images have the same height and width irrespective of the original image dimensions and equally preserve aspect ratio so that they all fill my imageView without leaving any whitespace or me having to crop

```
private static Bitmap resize(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
    float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

    int finalWidth = maxWidth;
    int finalHeight = maxHeight;
    if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
        finalWidth = (int) ((float)maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
    } else {
        finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
    }
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
    return image;
} else {
    return image;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not using `scaleType` on the ImageView itself? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: scaleType center leaves whitespace, centerCrop crops the image while fitXy stretches it..fit() in Picasso equally distorts the image

Comment: So you want all your images to have the **same** height and width (even if they are from various size at the beginning) and you want to keep the ratio but neither crop them nor have white space? I'm afraid it's impossible or I haven't understood what you try to achieve

Comment: apps like Instagram display images uniformly that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Instagram resizes and crops the images permanently when you import them. Then they have all the same size so they fit perfectly.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities when you want to display all the images to fit in the same size container: 1- resize them without keeping the ratio. In that case you have the entire image but the it's potentially distorted (don't do that). 2- resize them keeping the ratio. In that case you'll have either to have whitespaces but the entire image or to crop the image.

Comment: The other possibility is (if I'm correct) what Facebook does. You display a cropped image and the user can click on it to display the entire image.

Comment: yes I tried your third option early but its unpleasant to first see an image with people's heads cropped off before seeing the full image. If it were cropped from the bottom it'll be manageable. Thanks

Comment: True, but yeah you don't necessarily have to crop from the middle, you can crop the bottom of the image and you'll have a better chance to have something correct. After you can use complex recognition algorithms to detect what is in the image and crop it accordingly. It is to you to choose which option suits the most for you. But in any case what you wanted to do at the beginning is not possible.

Comment: you mean there's another attribute other than centerCrop which crops the bottom?

Comment: But if the user has to import the photos in your app, you can crop the image when the user imports him and let him choose where he wants the image to be cropped

Comment: No, you'll have to implement the crop yourself if you want to remove the bottom (if I'm correct)

Comment: I'm not using Picasso, but with Glide you can create your own 'Transformation' so you can probably do the same with Picasso. In your custom transformation just resize, crop,... the image as you want.